# How to execute a PostGre exe file with silent mode?

Tags: windows, powershell, executable, postgresql-9.1, windows-server-2012

Hy,

I would install PostGreSQL 9.1 on a Windows Server 2012.
I want to used a PowerShell script.
With my JDK executables file, I use `Start-Process "Myfile" -ArgumentList "/s" -Wait`
But the argument `\s` don't work with my PostGre executables file.

Have you an idea ?

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com or serverfault.com . Assuming by "postgre exe" file you mean "the PostgreSQL installer" ... read the manual for it. It has documentation on silent install options. Or search for "postgresql silent install windows".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this command : `Start-Process $installFile -ArgumentList "--unattendedmodeui minimal --mode unattended --prefix $dest --datadir $dest\data --servicepassword $pwd" -Wait`

Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Install-Postgres Powershell module, it's on [TechNet Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PostgreSQL-unattended-059a76c8).

The Install-PostgreSQL PowerShell module does the following:

- creates a local windows user that PostgreSQL will use
- downloads the PostgreSQL installer provided by EnterpriseDB
- installs Postgres unattended using the supplied parameters
- sets postgres windows user as owner of Postgres files and folders
- sets Postgres windows service to run under postgres local user
- creates pgpass.conf file in AppData
- copies configuration files to data directory
- opens the supplied port that PostgreSQL will use in the Windows
  Firewall

Usage

```
Import-Module Install-Postgres
Install-Postgres -User "postgres" -Password "ChangeMe!"
```